# bash script stop after execute external script(oh-my-zsh installer.sh)

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, zsh

I write a script to auto install zsh and set some default config.

```
function setup_zsh(){
    echo "####################################"
    echo "setup zsh"

    apt-get install -y zsh git curl
    sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
    # later code would not execute because now enter zsh shell

    writelines 'source /etc/profile' ~/.zshrc

    echo "setup zsh theme"
    if [ -s ~/.zshrc ]; then
        if grep -q 'ZSH_THEME' ~/.zshrc ; then
            sed -i 's/^ZSH_THEME=.*/ZSH_THEME="'${ZSH_THEME}'"/' ~/.zshrc
        else
            echo 'ZSH_THEME="'${ZSH_THEME}'"' >> ~/.zshrc
        fi
    fi
}
```

But I found when `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`  finishes, it would enter zsh shell, so later code would not execute. 
How do I work around this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because at the end this last line `env zsh` causes installer.sh run a `zsh` sub-shell; You can add and redirect `0>/dev/null` to `sh -c` to fail it to run a sub-shell.

```bsh
0>/dev/null sh -c "$(curl ....)"
```

You can check `0>/dev/null` behavior when running `0>/dev/null env zsh` and `enz zsh` after installation to see that `0>/dev/null env zsh` preventing to switch to `zsh` shell or any other shells.

This will also cause to fail/prevent when that wants to change your default shell when asking your password in below.

```bsh
if hash chsh >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      printf "${BLUE}Time to change your default shell to zsh!${NORMAL}\n"
      chsh -s $(grep /zsh$ /etc/shells | tail -1)
```